# Duplicates occurring across variables from different radio buttons

Tags: r, xml, shiny

In the following R Shiny application, I have three radio buttons (fnames, pars, and env). fnames and pars share a couple of similar parameters such as d13c, ri, rb, and rs.

**The Issues (all from the 2nd panel):**

1. When I change the value for d13c in pars and save the xml file, the change would occur in the xml file for d13c under pars and fnames. In the interface, the change would occur for pars, and not fnames
2. Let's say I clicked the pars radio button and I didn't make any change, and clicked the update button. All the values for d13c, ri, rb, and rs from fnames would change to the values of pars (in the xml only and only the interface).
3. For example, let's the default value for d13c in pars is FALSE and in fnames it's 'abcd'. Once the update button is clicked, the value for d13c in fnames would change to FALSE (once again, this change only occurs in the xml, and not the interface)
4. When I click on either fnames or pars, and attempt to make a change, a glitch occurs

**What I'd like to do:**

1. When a change occurs in pars, I don't want it to effect anything in fnames
2. I don't want the values for fnames to change unless I'm on the fnames radio button and click the update button there
3. Figure out what's causing the glitch

**Below is my code**

```
library(shiny)
library(xml2)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyBS)
library(XML)
library(glue)

# Read the XML file and extract the options
xml_data <- read_xml("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/leaf_default.xml")

# Find parent nodes
parent_nodes <- xml_data %>% xml_children() %>% xml_name() 

# Find grandchild node names for each parent node
fnames <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//fnames/leaf")
fnames_names <- xml_children(fnames) %>% xml_name()
fnames_values <- xml_children(fnames)  %>% xml_text()
fnames_options <- read_xml("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/leaf/leaf_options.xml")
fnames_gc <- xml_find_all(fnames, ".//*[count(*) > 1]") %>% xml_name()

pars <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//pars/leaf")
pars_names <- xml_children(pars) %>% xml_name()
pars_values <- xml_children(pars) %>% xml_text()
pars_gc <- xml_find_all(pars, ".//*[count(*) > 1]") %>% xml_name()

env <- xml_data %>% xml_find_first(".//env/leaf")
env_names <- xml_children(env) %>% xml_name()
env_values <- xml_children(env) %>% xml_text()
env_gc <- xml_find_all(env, ".//*[count(*) > 1]") %>% xml_name()

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, 
           wellPanel(
             prettyRadioButtons(
               "parts",
               "Please Select",
               choices = parent_nodes,
               status = "danger",
               fill = TRUE
               )
             )
           ), 
    column(10, 
           bsCollapse(id = "collapse_ex", open = "Parameters", multiple = TRUE,
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters w/Sub-Script", uiOutput("gc_params_ui"), uiOutput("gc_textboxes"), style = "success", 
                                      fluidRow(column(12, align = "right", actionButton("fir_update_button", "Update")))), 
                      bsCollapsePanel("Parameters", uiOutput("ui"), style = "info", 
                                      fluidRow(column(12, align = "right", actionButton("sec_update_button", "Update"))))
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  pars_gc_names <- reactiveValues(names = NULL)
  fnames_gc_names <- reactiveValues(names = NULL)
  
  output$gc_params_ui <- renderUI({})
  output$gc_textboxes <- renderUI({})
  
  observeEvent(input$parts, {
    parent_node <- input$parts
    all_grandchild_nodes <- switch(parent_node, "fnames" = fnames_names, "pars" = pars_names, "env" = env_names, NULL)
    
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      fluidRow(
        lapply(all_grandchild_nodes, function(node_name) {
          if (parent_node == "fnames") {
            if (node_name %in% fnames_gc) {
              return(NULL)
            }
            if (node_name %in% fnames_names) {
              node_index <- match(node_name, fnames_names)
              default_value <- fnames_values[node_index]
              
              column(6, textInput(paste0("fnames_", node_name), label = node_name, value = if (is.null(input[[paste0("fnames_", node_name)]]) || input[[paste0("fnames_", node_name)]] == default_value) default_value else input[[paste0("fnames_", node_name)]]))
            }
          } else if (parent_node == "pars") {
            if (node_name %in% pars_gc) {
              return(NULL)
            }
            if (node_name %in% pars_names) {
              node_index <- match(node_name, pars_names)
              default_value <- pars_values[node_index]
              
              column(6, textInput(node_name, label = node_name, value = if (is.null(input[[node_name]]) || input[[node_name]] == default_value) default_value else input[[node_name]]))
            }
          } else if (parent_node == "env") {
            if (node_name %in% env_names) {
              node_index <- match(node_name, env_names)
              default_value <- env_values[node_index]
              
              column(6, textInput(node_name, label = node_name, value = if (is.null(input[[node_name]]) || input[[node_name]] == default_value) default_value else input[[node_name]]))
            }
          }
        })
      )
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$fir_update_button, {
    parent_node <- input$parts
    updated_xml_data <- xml_data
    selected_option <- input$gc_params
    
    if (parent_node == "fnames") {
      for (node_name in fnames_gc_names$names) {
        new_value <- input[[node_name]]
        node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//fnames/leaf/", selected_option, "/", node_name))
        
        if (!is.null(node)) {
          xml_text(node) <- new_value
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (parent_node == "pars") {
      for (node_name in pars_gc_names$names) {
        new_value <- input[[node_name]]
      
        node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//pars/leaf/", selected_option, "/", node_name))

        if (!is.null(node)) {
          xml_text(node) <- new_value
        }
      }
    }
    

    new_xml_file <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/test/updated_leaf.xml"
    write_xml(updated_xml_data, new_xml_file)

    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Update Successful",
      "The XML file has been updated.",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$sec_update_button, {
    parent_node <- input$parts
    updated_xml_data <- xml_data
  
    if (parent_node == "pars") {
      for (node_name in pars_names) {
        if (node_name %in% pars_gc) {next}
        new_value <- input[[node_name]]
        default_value <- pars_values[match(node_name, pars_names)]
        
        if (!is.null(new_value) && new_value != default_value) { # new_value is check whether it's not NULL and it differes from default_value
          node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//pars/leaf/", node_name))
          
          if (!is.null(node)) {
            xml_text(node) <- new_value
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (parent_node == "fnames") {
      for (node_name in fnames_names) {
        if (node_name %in% fnames_gc) {next}
        new_value <- input[[node_name]]
        default_value <- fnames_values[match(node_name, fnames_names)]

        if (!is.null(new_value) && new_value != default_value) { # new_value is check whether it's not NULL and it differes from default_value
          node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//fnames/leaf/", node_name))
          
          if (!is.null(node)) {
            xml_text(node) <- new_value
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    if (parent_node == "env") {
      for (node_name in env_names) {
        if (node_name %in% env_gc) {next}
        new_value <- input[[node_name]]
        
        node <- xml_find_first(updated_xml_data, paste0(".//env/leaf/", node_name))
        
        if (!is.null(node)) {
          xml_text(node) <- new_value
        }
      }
    }
    
    new_xml_file <- "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/test/updated_leaf.xml"
    write_xml(updated_xml_data, new_xml_file, declaration = TRUE)
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Update Successful",
      "The XML file has been updated.",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Below is the data from the xml file**

```
<default>
  <fnames>
    <leaf>
      <sys>'f_sys_enzymek'</sys>
      <rd>'f_rd_lin_vcmax'</rd>
      <rl_rd>'f_scalar_none'</rl_rd>
      <gstar>'f_gstar_f1980'</gstar>
      <ri>'f_r_zero'</ri>
      <rs>'f_rs_medlyn2011'</rs>
      <rb>'f_rb_leafdim'</rb>
      <cica_ratio>'f_cica_ratio_constant'</cica_ratio>
      <d13c>'f_d13c_classical'</d13c>
    </leaf>
  </fnames>
  <pars>
    <leaf>
      <d13c>FALSE</d13c>
      <fnr>7.16</fnr>
      <rs>6.66666666666667</rs>
      <rb>0.1</rb>
      <ri>6.66666666666667</ri>
      <R>8.31446</R>
    </leaf>
  </pars>
  <env>
    <leaf>
      <ca_conc>400</ca_conc>
      <o2_conc>0.21</o2_conc>
      <par>1000</par>
      <water_l>0</water_l>
      <sphag_l>0</sphag_l>
      <temp>25</temp>
      <vpd>0</vpd>
      <rh>0.8</rh>
      <atm_press>101325</atm_press>
      <wind>1</wind>
    </leaf>
  </env>
</default>
```

Comment: Add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (not relying on files which are saved on your computer). Also shorten the body of your question and try to reduce the amount of code and text in order to make it more understandable.